# "React" how to pass event to adjacent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make a click on the button in one component and on this click call a function in the adjacent one. What's the easiest way?

I implemented like this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-l5beyi But I think you can do it much easier. React is new to me, and this construction looks strange ...

```js
const App = () => {
  const [isAdded, setIsAdded] = useState(false);

  function handleClick(status) {
    setIsAdded(status)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentFirst
        HandleClick={handleClick}
      />
      <ComponentSecond
        isAdded={isAdded}
        handleCreate={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const ComponentFirst = ({ HandleClick }) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={HandleClick}
    >button</button>
  )
}

const ComponentSecond = (props) => {
  let { isAdded, handleCreate } = props;
  const result = () => {
    alert('work')
    console.log('work')
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isAdded) {
      result()
      handleCreate(false);
    }
  }, [isAdded, handleCreate]);

  return (
    <></>
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you managed with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your (contrived, I suppose) example the second component doesn't render anything, so it doesn't exist. The work should be done by the parent component:

```
const App = () => {
  const handleClick = React.useCallback((status) => {
    alert(`work ${status}`);
    // or maybe trigger some asynchronous work?
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentFirst handleClick={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
};

const ComponentFirst = ({ handleClick }) => {
  return <button onClick={() => handleClick("First!")}>button</button>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) to which any component can listen to.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentFirst />
      <ComponentSecond />
    </div>
  );
}

const ComponentFirst = () => {

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    // Create the event.
    const event = new CustomEvent("myCustomEventName", {
      detail: "Some information"
    });

    // target can be any Element or other EventTarget.
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>button</button>;
};

const ComponentSecond = (props) => {
  function eventHandler(e) {
    console.log("Dispatched Detail: " + e.detail);
  }

  //Listen for this event on the window object
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("myCustomEventName", eventHandler);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("myCustomEventName", eventHandler);
    };
  });

  return <></>;
};
```